# How can ∈ be less than/ greater than something?

Tags: notation

How can ∈ be less than/ greater than something? Specifically in the equation |a∗a−x| ≤ ∈. From my understanding ∈ means 'is an element of" and used like this: 'Let a∈A' means 'Let a be an element of A'. How can it be less than/ greater than something?
Thanks

Comment: In many contexts, $\in$ is a binary relation. Binary relations can be ordered.

Comment: Where did you find the inequality?

Comment: Seems to be a lower case epsilon.

Comment: where was I: in Latex, set membership is $\in$ while the two main versions of epsilon are $\epsilon$ and $\varepsilon$   It would appear that you or someone printing mixed up $\in$ and $\epsilon$

Comment: Where did you find that equation. It would be nice to provide it so we can see how it is being put as.

Comment: @Will Jaggy quite possibly

Comment: Not to mention that $\in$ was denoted by $\varepsilon$ in some older texts, and is still sometimes referred to as "epsilon relation" (e.g. $\in$-induction is called "epsilon-induction" sometimes).

Comment: It's a matter of typography.  [Peano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_(mathematics)#/media/File:First_usage_of_the_symbol_%E2%8%88.png) used an "uncial" $\epsilon$.  I don't know how this morphed into the stylized $\in$, or how readily available the latter would be in the days before TeX.

Answer (score 5):

There are two similar-looking but different-meaning symbols.

"$\in$" is used for "element of a set".

"$\epsilon$" (Greek letter epsilon) is used for a number or variable (in your case, probably a positive Real number).

"$\varepsilon$" is another form of epsilon.